# Cant center an image inside of a div?

Tags: html, css

So basically, I am trying to center a div with an image inside of a div with left and right divs and the middle div won't center. I have tried positioning absolute and setting `left:0` and `right:0`

here is the structure of the html logoLeft is `float:left` and logoRight is `float:right`.

[image: post image]

Thank you.

Comment: try : `float: none;margin: 0 auto;` to center div

Comment: You need to post the actual html/css you are using

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I added an external div to align the items

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="logoLeft"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="logoRight"></div>
</div>
```

In css we do the magic

```
.flex{
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `display: table` with a container :

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="logoLeft"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="logoRight"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS :

```
.table {
  display: table;
}
.table > div {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```